# Does Each thread in c++ has its own memory allocation limits

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating a single thread. But when I try to allocate some memory in the function being called by the thread, I am getting `std::bad_array_new_length` exception. Now, I can see from htop, that I still have free memory(out of the total ~100 Gb). Further, the code works when I call the same function in the main thread.

This is the code I am using to spawn the single thread:

```
#include <thread>
vector<thread> threads;

for(int i=0; i<1; i++ ) 
    threads.push_back(thread(my_func, param1, param2));

for(_int i=0; i<threads.size(); i++)
    threads[i].join();
```

I have two question here : 
Does thread has its own memory limit(as in the stack space). If yes, how to make it see the whole memory as its own?

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: Yes, it has. Any further stack allocation (`alloca`) is likely OS specific.

Comment: Generally all threads share a heap, they have their own stack and it is not unusual for the main thread to have a larger stack than other threads. Show a [mcve] for more help

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I have made that check, thanks.

Comment: @bolov, this is the part from a larger code base, will try to create a MCV example and edit the answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heap is shared among all threads (although allocators like [TCMalloc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Thread-caching_malloc_(tcmalloc)) utilize thread-specific subsets of the heap for short-lived allocations for efficiency).  However, [`bad_array_new_length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length) isn’t about memory exhaustion: it’s about allocation requests that are impossibly large or negative.